# How can I get "Hot Question" widget of askubuntu ?

Tags: support

*Hii There ..*

when i visit **omgubuntu.co.uk** and i find a ***hot question*** widget in the rightside of that website, how can i get the script or anything else, so i can add the widget in our web ?

*thanks for your help*

Comment: Probably some one answering this can answer this also "how to see hot questions from askubuntu.com site"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't provide this widget, the guys at OMG! Ubuntu! made it themselves (as far as I can tell anyway).

Take a look at our [API help](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage), especially the [**`questions?sort=Hot`**](http://api.askubuntu.com/1.1/questions?sort=Hot) method. It should get you started quite quickly.

If you don't want to implement all of the API calls yourself, and depending on the Language you're using on the server, you'll probably find something suitable in this [List of Libraries](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-libraries) for the Stack Exchange API.

For example, George Edison has made easy to use libraries for [Javascript](https://stackapps.com/questions/362/stackscript-javascript-wrapper) and [PHP](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php-now-with-v1-1-support).

Comment: In addition check out [StackTack](http://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) if you're looking to provide constantly updated StackExchange content on your blog without becoming a stale content farm